# Let A be a matrix, 2 an eigenvalue of A, and v an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue 2. What is A^5v?

Tags: linear-algebra

v is the vector {-1, 3, -3}

I know that Av = 2v

2^5 = 32

32 is then a scalar, multiplying the vector {-1, 3, -3}

Giving me the vector A^5v= {-32, 96, -96}

Is this correct? I have a feeling more needs to be done to the eigenvector than what I did here.

Comment: Why?  It's an eigenvector; you should only have to multiply it by a scalar.

Comment: By the way, you should write $Av = 2v$, not $Ax = 2x$.  It doesn't scale arbitrary vectors by $2$, only the eigenvector $v$.

Comment: Ahh. That's true. My mistake. So this is correct?

Comment: Seems right to me.